# How to says logs analytics?

Tags: информатика

I speak Russian but I do not know computer terms. How to look for logs analytics. Data mining would be

```
сбор данных
```

Yandex translates log data as

```
каротажные данные
```

but it actually refers to geology not to computers.

How could we translate logs mining or logs analytics?

Comment: without context сбор регистрационных журналов and анализ (данных) регистрационных журналов or данные анализа регистрационных журналов

Comment: "data mining" ≠ "сбор данных". According to wikipedia: "Data mining is the process of discovering patterns in large data sets involving methods at the intersection of machine learning, statistics, and database systems".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Анализ логов" or (depending on context) "аналитика данных, полученных из логов" would be the best phrase one can use.

If you speak Russian you must know that Russian historically was ok with borrowing terms from foreign languages. Not only "регистрационный журнал" suggested in comments also consists of two foreign words but also the usage of such term is de-facto negligible to saying just "логи".

Comment: How about "data mining"? I'm not quite sure if it is indeed translated to "сбор данных". At least I've heard some people to say "дата майнинг". I'd also add that Russian computer terms is a terrible mess of actually translated words (mouse - мышь), words that are totally different (random access memory - оперативная память), and words that are just transliterated (a build - билд). And later ones sometimes can be morphed (to build - билдить)

Comment: And there ar many word to express the same thing."A build" may be a "билд" ("билдить") or a "сборка" ("собирать"). Microsoft, for example, likes to make quite a wild translations of CS terms to Russian. It is getting worse with developing of autotranslations.